# Casting in C++ Using Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

Having a little trouble understanding the concept of casting in C++. How does the casting work when using pointers? When is casting a Compile Time issue or a Run Time one?

```
// class type-casting
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CDummy {
    float i,j;
};

class CAddition {
    int x,y;
  public:
    CAddition (int a, int b) { x=a; y=b; }
    int result() { return x+y;}
};

int main () {
  CDummy d;
  CAddition * padd;
  padd = (CAddition*) &d;
  cout << padd->result();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Don't C-style cast in C++. Use [`static_cast<...>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast). I'm not sure what the intent is here since converting that pointer is *undefined behaviour*, so this is pretty much garbage code from that point forward. Nothing you do with `padd` can be trusted.

Comment: FWIW, your code is illegal and has undefined behavior.  You can't cast one object to another except for certain circumstances.

Comment: You might want to look at conversion vs. casting, as in write a `CAddition` constructor that takes a `const CDummy&` as an argument. This means you can do things like `CAddition a = d`.

Comment: Yes i know it is. But the compiler doesn't prevent such a thing. That's my question; What is happening exactly in such a code

Comment: `Yes i know it is. But the compiler doesn't prevent such a thing` -- The compiler can do whatever it wants to, since the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Note: I'm not trying to correct the code.I'm just trying to know what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: @HusseinJaber Are you ready to dig into all of the compilers ever created, all the options, and see what they do with this code?

Comment: is your question about this particular piece of code or about casts in general? If it is the latter then the code is not usable as an example (because it has undefined behavior)

Comment: I want to know more about casting in c++ in general. It looks way more harder than that of Java which has type checking and JVM.

Comment: @HusseinJaber C++ also doesn't have array bounds checking unlike Java.  Accept that C++ allows you to do things that are undefined.

Comment: Java is not C++ and C++ is not Java. What works in Java has no bearing on C++ at all. C++ is a much lower-level language and when you C-style cast it just does *exactly what you say*, regardless of consequences. Java will steadfastly refuse to do certain things. C++ will get out of the way if you want to shoot yourself in the foot multiple times, aggressively. I'd suggest walking through this code in a debugger and look at how utterly trashed the `padd` pointer appears to be in the debug view.

Comment: My advice on casting: Don't, at least until you have a firm foundation in C++.  C++ is not a safe language and lets you really muck about in memory.  Unless you are dealing with an inheritance chain, or casting basic types, I would hold off on casting until you really understand how the C++ abstract machine works.  Some of these [good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) can really give you that knowledge and they will go over casting and all the pitfalls associated with it.

Comment: @HusseinJaber Casting is endemic in Java, since casting was (don't know if it still is) the prevalent method to get back an object from a container class.  Bringing Java habits to C++, such as casting everywhere, is not wise.  There is no runtime "Bad cast" error in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know more about casting in c++ in general. It looks way more harder than that of Java which has type checking and JVM.

C++ does check types. By using a c-style cast, you explicitly ask to bypass all security the type systems gives you. You should not use c-style casts in C++, but rather [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast), [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) and in rare cases `const_cast` and in even more rare cases `reinterpret_cast`.

If you replace your c-style cast

```
padd = (CAddition*) &d;
```

with the C++ cast:

```
padd = static_cast<CAddition*>(&d);
```

then the compiler will tell you that what you are doing is wrong:

```
prog.cc:19:36: error: invalid static_cast from type 'CDummy*' to type 'CAddition*'
   padd = static_cast<CAddition*>(&d);
```

I don't think it can be more clear: A `CDummy*` is not a `CAddition*` so you should not cast between those types.

Because you do, your code has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Neither the C++ standard nor compilers bother to do anything meaningful with code that has undefined behavior (hence the name: it is simply not defined what you will get).

**PS** In your example you can provide a conversion:

```
class CAddition {
    int x,y;
  public:
    CAddition (const CDummy& cd) : x(cd.i),y(cd.j) {}
    CAddition (int a, int b) : x(a),y(b) {}
    int result() { return x+y;}
};
```

Using such a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) you can create a `CAddition` from a `CDummy` easily (you would need to make the members `public` in `CDummy` or provide some other means to access them to make this work).

**PPS** I was a bit sloppy when above I told you that the C++ casts are safer. They still make a good tool to shoot yourself in the foot. Needing to cast is usually a code/design smell. Don't fall into the trap of silencing compiler warnings / errors by putting casts in your code. This may be fine in Java, but it makes things just worse in C++.